# Measure screen change response / time?

Tags: performance, xaml, winrt-xaml, stopwatch

Is there a tool that captures the time it takes for my computer display to change?

Specifically, I'm measuring how long it takes for a Windows 8 app to change from 1 View to the Next. This is to measure performance.

Right now, I have some Stopwatch inside the code but it only measures the calculations. Actual rendering in the screen is not.

I try to measure it using a manual stopwatch and I time it manually. However, it can be inconsistent because of human intervention.

Is there a more consistent way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check **Application Timeline** tool (available with Visual Studio 2015). It could probably help you.

[image: Timeline]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC790153.jpeg))</sub>

Analyze UI responsiveness with the Application Timeline tool
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn957934.aspx